# What is wrong with INT32_MIN/-1?

Tags: c

John Regehr's blog post [*A Guide to Undefined Behavior in C and C++, Part 1*](https://blog.regehr.org/archives/213) contains the following "safe" function for "performing integer division without executing undefined behavior":

```
int32_t safe_div_int32_t (int32_t a, int32_t b) {
  if ((b == 0) || ((a == INT32_MIN) && (b == -1))) {
    report_integer_math_error();
    return 0;
  } else {
    return a / b;
  }
}
```

I'm wondering what is wrong with the division (a/b) when a = INT32_MIN and b = -1. Is it undefined? If so why?

Comment: This has nothing to do with standard C, it is 2's complements that is not symmetric. For example, using 32 bits, you can model the following range: [-(2^31), (2^31)-1]

Comment: @AraK: It *does* have to do with standard C: the fixed-width signed types defined in `<stdint.h>` (like the `int32_t` being used here) are defined to have a two's complement representation.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think it's because the absolute value of INT32_MIN is 1 larger than INT32_MAX. So INT32_MIN/-1 actually equals INT32_MAX + 1 which would overflow.

So for 32-bit integers, there are 4,294,967,296 values.
There are 2,147,483,648 values for negative numbers (-2,147,483,648 to -1).
There is 1 value for zero (0).
There are 2,147,483,647 values for positive numbers (1 to 2,147,483,647) because 0 took 1 value away from the positive numbers.

Comment: Correct. This is the only possible pair of values that will overflow when dividing 32-bit integers.

Answer (score 3):

This is because `int32_t` is represented using two's-complement, and numbers with `N` bits in two's-complement range from `−2^(N−1)` to `2^(N−1)−1`.  Therefore, when you carry out the division, you get: `-2^(31) / -1 = 2^(N-1)`.  Notice that the result is larger than `2^(N-1)-1`, meaning you get an overflow!

Answer (score 2):

The other posters are correct about the causes of the overflow.  The implication of the overflow on most machines is that INT_MIN / -1 => INT_ MIN.   The same thing happens when multiplying by -1.  This is an unexpected and possibly dangerous result.  I've seen a fixed-point motor controller go out of control because it didn't check for this condition.

Answer (score 1):

Because INT32_MIN is defined as (-INT32_MAX-1) = -(INT32_MAX+1) and when divided by -1, this would be (INT32+MAX) => there is an integer overflow. I must say, that is a nice way to check for overflows. Thoughtfully written code. +1 to the developer.

Comment: I don't know that replacing the division operator with a function named "save_div_in32_t" is "thoughtful"...

Comment: The thoughtful comment was for taking into consideration the integer overflow. I have seen very few programmers taking care about these  situations (of course most developers work on application specific code and let the framework handle these, but once in a while one is bound to be bitten by these kinds of situations).